# Fill properties with some default value using Moq

Tags: c#, nunit, moq

I have a unit test which validates an object against an XSD using `SchemaSet` and `XmlReaderSettings`.

e.g.

```cs
public class Foo {
    public string MyProperty1 { get; set; }
    public Bar MyProperty2 { get; set; }
}
```

where `Bar` is another class with similar properties and maybe more classes

As this class can get quite large and (recursively) complex and the data in the properties needs to be filled to create the XML nodes I want to automate filling all the properties with some default value (e.g. all strings filed with `"RandomString"` and all decimals with `12`).

Moq has the SetupAllProperties feature but this sets all values to it's default, which is null for a string.

Unit Test

```cs
        [Test]
        public void XmlTest()
        {
            var foo = new Foo
            {
                MyProperty1 = "Property1"
                MyProperty2 = new Bar
                {
                    ...
                }
            };
            var xml = foo.SerializeToXmlString();
            var result = validator.Validate(xml);

            Assert.That(result.IsValid, Is.True);
        }
```

Is there a way to automatically fill all properties with a specified default value in Moq? Or is there some other tool that has these properties?

Comment: Rather than _describing_ your code, _show_ your code with a [mre].

Comment: "the data in the properties does not matter to me " I think this is the wrong attitude. One of the points of unit tests is that they do the same thing, every time it's run.  Your data should be different, constant, and not random.  (By different, I mean each field should have a unique value.  There shouldn't be 2 decimal fields that hold 12, otherwise, you don't know when you are assigning the wrong value).

Comment: The values really do not matter as it generates a xml message where I validate it against an XSD. Should have made that more clear, but updated the question

Comment: @DTul check out [AutoFixture](https://autofixture.github.io/) along with its auto moq extension.

Comment: In your simple example, is `SerializeToXmlString` an extension method? Can you update and include the relevant details in your example so a proper answer can be provided.

Comment: That implementation of how the xml is generated is irrelevant to the question. The question is about how to fill a C# object recursively with default/mock data. As to why that is necessary or a bad idea is not relevant to answering the question. Your AutoFixture recommendation seems to be doing the trick. Thank you for that.